# statfulWidget with key concept

Tags: flutter

i am studying key in flutter. and in explanation, when i want swap widget in `statefulWidget` i need to add key value. because when flutter check `element structure` if type, state are not same they don't response. this is how i understand.

```dart
void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: PositionedTiles()));

class PositionedTiles extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PositionedTilesState();
}

class PositionedTilesState extends State<PositionedTiles> {

List<Widget> tiles = [
  StatefulColorfulTile(key: UniqueKey()), // Keys added here
  StatefulColorfulTile(key: UniqueKey()),
];

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Row(children: tiles),
     floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
         child: Icon(Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied), onPressed: swapTiles),
   );
 }

 swapTiles() {
   setState(() {
     tiles.insert(1, tiles.removeAt(0));
   });
 }
}



class StatefulColorfulTile extends StatefulWidget {
  StatefulColorfulTile({Key key}) : super(key: key);  // NEW CONSTRUCTOR

  @override
  ColorfulTileState createState() => ColorfulTileState();
}

class ColorfulTileState extends State<ColorfulTile> {
  Color myColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myColor = UniqueColorGenerator.getColor();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: myColor,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(70.0),
        ));
  }
}
```

but i saw this code.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      value
          ? const SizedBox()
          : const Placeholder(),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            value = !value;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
      !value
          ? const SizedBox()
          : const Placeholder(),
    ],
  );
}
```

this code is also use `statefulWidget`. in this code when user taps Box it's changed but i think there're no key value and in element structure there are different type(one is SizedBox and the other is placeHolder) so i think there aren't changed. why they're changed? what i misunderstand?

Comment: Keys help in preserving state. In the case of a `List` how do you differentiate between two items? In the second snippet it is pretty clear there is one at the bottom and one(`SizedBox`) at the top.

Comment: sorry i added `List` code

Comment: I hope you understood my comment. In a COLLECTION of same types it is necessary assign a unique key to each one of them. It isn't necessary when it is not a COLLECTION.

Comment: like list above first one?

Comment: The first snippet seems to have a single list right.

Comment: the collection what you said is first snippet's List?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197113/discussion-between-10101010-and-evergreen).